# Change Between Chrome and Firefox per Scenario in Selenium Java ( CUCUMBER , JUnit)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber

How can i change between browsers when i run a specific scenario in Java?

I already imported the 2 browsers so far i can only open both of them using the code

```
public void accessURL() throws Throwable
{

    Registration_Steps_1.setUp();
    for(String browser : browserDriver)
    {

        driver=Registration_Steps_1.initiateBrowserDriver(browser);
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(baseUrl);    
        super.driver = driver;

    }

}
```

after that i cannot run the other methods for each of the browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to run test on both browser if yes, user testng suite and pass browser parameter from testng suite.

Second approach setup browser type in configuration file read from there and run test on browser as mention in configuration file.

Comment: Actually for example i have 5 Scenario's and for Each Scenario i want it to run on Firefox then Google Chrome after that it will move on to the 2nd Scenario then Firefox , google chrome and so on. ( I am using Cucumber With Selenium , JUnit and Java )

Answer (score 0):

the next methods might probably be running by the second browser coming from your browserDriver.

driver object will be a fresh instance of webdriver interface and will not have any session.

so, if you want to run a flow involving login with two browsers, it will not be possible as the login session will recorded in the browser with which you logged in.

if it is a general url traversing stuff you can do with two browsers by calling the second browser by instantiating the driver object again in the middle.